# How can I prevent compound component from re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using react context, and all it contains at the moment are 3 items: `contacts` and `editingContact`, and `editContact`:

```
interface ContactsContextProps {
  contacts: Contact[];
  editingContact: Contact;
  editContact: (contact: Contact) => () => void // being lazy and this is from an onClick
}

const ContactsContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContactsContextProps>>({
  editContact: (contact: Contact) => () => {}
})

const ContactsProvider: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<Contact[]>();
  const [editingContact, setEditingContact] = useState<Contact>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
   // fetch contacts, and setContacts(contacts)
  }, [])

  const editContact = React.useCallback((contact: Contact) => {
    return function() {
      setEditingContact(contact);
    }
  })

  return (
    <ContactsContext.Provider
      value={{
        editingContact,
        editContact,
        contacts
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ContactsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Here's how it is being used:

```
const ContactsList: React.FunctionComponent<{
  contacts: Contact[];
}> = React.memo(props => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.contacts.map(contact => (
        <Card key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
});

const Wrapper: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const contactsCtx = React.useContext(ContactsContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Box className={styles.main}>
        <Header />
        {contactsCtx.contacts && <ContactsList contacts={contactsCtx.contacts} />}
      </Box>
      {contactsCtx.editingContact && <EditContactModal />}
    </>
  );
};
```

The `<Card />` only has an edit button right now, which calls `contactsContext.editContact()`.  However, each time this is called, all the Cards re-render.  I placed a `console.log('card')` in each Card, and it logs `card` 10 times (I have 10 contacts right now).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't avoid that, that's the way react works, every change will render everything again, but relax it will render only in memory and the changes won't reflect on your DOM tree. Search about "react virtual dom"

Comment: Thanks.  what happens if I have 5000 contacts?  I don't want the contacts to re-render just because a modal has opened up.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It will render in memory first on "virtual dom" and after that It will do a diff operation with the real dom and only change what it's need :D

Answer (score 1):

There has been a discussion in a [React Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693), basically there is 3 possible solutions for this:

- Option 1 (Preferred): Split contexts that don't change together
- Option 2: Split your component in two, put `memo` in between
- Option 3: One component with `useMemo` inside

You should check the link for examples about it.